# How to reload page after 3 login attempts with 401 unauthorised access error? in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

When try to access site i created after 3 login attempts  it gives unauthorised access error-401. how can i reload page after 3 attempts in asp.net. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I like to know where or how you get the error "unauthorised access error-401"? Is it coming from the Web server? Your problem may not be solvable if you're dealing with a server you don't have the proper authority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to store and manage these thing at backend(mean to say at SQL SERVER or any other server). If you are using the SQL SERVER then follow the following steps:
1). add a new column of int type in table named as **invalidattempts**
2). Now in **logincheck** Stored Proc, if the username and password are not authorized then update invalid column in table. and write the following code.

```
Declare @PasswordDB varchar(100)
Declare @InvalidDB int
if exists(select 1 from tblUser where email=@email)
begin
    set @PasswordDB= (Select password from tblUser where email=@email)
    if @PasswordDB=@Password
        begin
                print'login Successfully.'
        end
    else
        begin
            set @InvalidDB=(select invalidattempts from tblUser where email=@email)
update tblUser set invalidAttepmts=@InvalidDB+1 where email=@email 
select 3
end
end
else
begin
select 2
print'username does not exists.'
end
```

When you got 3 from sp then show an alert message that "You have made 3 invalid attempts thats is"

Comment: @ visions sure will give it a  try